# Adding packages to node_modules folder of a released app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, module, yarnpkg

## Problem

When I use components from the [Voyager](https://github.com/vega/voyager) project in my React v15.4.2 app, I have the following errors:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of
>   `DataSelectorBase`.
>
> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from
>   the file it's defined in. Check the render method of
>   `DataSelectorBase`.

## Local version works, released version breaks

I tried `npm link` to Voyager `2.0.0-alpha.20` locally, and my app works without the above error.

Yet when I use the **same version** of Voyager released on npm (also `2.0.0-alpha.20`), I have the above error.

Then, I found out that when I add these two packages (`react-modal`, `element-class`) to:

```
[my_app]/node_modules/datavoyager/node_modules/
```

my app works again!

## Questions

- What determines which packages should go into the `node_modules` folder of a released app? (I'm using `yarn 1.3.2` to install my dependencies, so `yarn` will decide what packages to nest under Voyager?)
- Is nested `node_modules` even a good practice?
- In my case, how do I add the two packages to the released version of Voyager?

Comment: can you check that `render` method has return or not ?

Comment: Hi @PraveenKumar, my problem is a bit tricky because it only happens when I use the released version of Voyager. When I `npm link` to the local version, things are fine. How can I check if `render` returned or not in the released version?